# REST API - Issue connecting JS app when CORS and Remote Site are both setup properly

Tags: rest, jsforce, cors

I cannot connect to Salesforce to automatically create accounts from my javascript app. I continue to get the error:

"Failed to load https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://www.nthround.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Here is my code snippet:

```
var jsforce = require('jsforce');
var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
   oauth2 : {
      loginUrl : 'https://login.salesforce.com',
      clientId : 'CLIENT_ID',
      clientSecret : 'CLIENT_SECRET',
      redirectUri : 'https://nthround.io'
   }
});
conn.login('USERNAME', 'xxxpasswordxxxXXXsecuritytokenXXXX', function(err, userInfo) {
   if (err) { return console.error(err); }
   console.log(conn.accessToken);
   console.log(conn.instanceUrl);
   console.log("User ID: " + userInfo.id);console.log("Org ID: " + userInfo.organizationId);
});

conn.sobject("Account").create({ Name : 'My Account #1' }, function(err, ret) {
   if (err || !ret.success) { return console.error(err, ret); }
      console.log("Created record id : " + ret.id);
});
```

My app was created using Meteor. I followed the steps on the JSForce documentation to setup (npm install jsforce command). I've gone through and created a connected app for my app and I put the URL "https://nthround.io" into the CORS and Remote Site Settings sections of Salesforce with no effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Add the following in CORS https://www.nthround.io .Notice you need www.  As well

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped... I put https:// www. nthround.io (without spaces) in CORS. Any further suggestions?